# d3 color models v. philips hue

Tags: d3.js

the philips hue bulb supports three different color models (temperature in mireds, hue/saturation, and cie1931).

since cie1931 is the 'native' model used by the bulb, most of the time that's the model reported by the bulb.

my naive thinking  was to use d3.lab(1, cie1931.x, cie1931.y).rgb(), but this isn't right (all the colors come out very close to black).

could a color model guru point me in the direction of mapping cie1931[x,y] to one of the models supported by d3 ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Philips Hue SDK for iOS has an [Application Note](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDKiOS/blob/master/ApplicationDesignNotes/RGB%20to%20xy%20Color%20conversion.md) which explains how to convert the XY values to RGB. Maybe you can adopt this to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
d3.cie1931 = {
// https://gist.github.com/AaronH/30c50aa4b161f8169c3d

  rgb : function(x, y) {
    var r, g, b, z;

    z = 1 - (x + y);

/*
   |R|   | X |   | 3.2333         -1.5262         0.2791 |
   |G| = | Y | * |-0.8268          2.4667         0.3323 |
   |B|   | Z |   | 0.1294          0.1983         2.0280 |
 */
    r =      (x *  3.2333) + (y * -1.5262) + (z * 0.2791);
    g =      (x * -0.8268) + (y *  2.4667) + (z * 0.3323);
    b =      (x *  0.1294) + (y *  0.1983) + (z * 2.0280);
    return d3.rgb (Math.max(0, Math.min(255, r * 255)),
                   Math.max(0, Math.min(255, g * 255)),
                   Math.max(0, Math.min(255, b * 255)));
  }
};
```